# Is there a way I can automate the collection of Sticky Resin?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I can't use a normal Harvester/Seeder combination with Rubber Tree Saplings as the Saplings have a drop rate that is entirely too unreliable to continue the cycle for very long.  Is there a reliable self-sustaining means of harvesting Sticky Resin for use in an Industrial Centrifuge for rubber and plant matter?

I am playing with a hybrid Unhinged/Unleashed pack.

I have every mod in Unhinged installed and these mods as well from Unleashed:

- Adv Power Management
- Adv Solar Panels
- Biblio Craft Mods (all three)
- Binnies Mods
- Computer Craft
- Damage Indicators
- Equivalent Exchange 3
- Extra Utilities
- GraviSuite
- Magic Bees
- Misc Periphreals
- ObsidiPlates
- Plugins for Forestry
- Soul Shards
- ThaumCraft

I also installed:

- Logistics Pipes
- Infernal Mobs
- Adv Machines

Comment: "Hybrid" doesn't convey any information about what mods are running. Can you be more specific? Like, "Unleashed + X, Y, and Z mods from Unhinged" or something?

Comment: I haven't tried either of those, but the older version of the Direwolf20 pack, the Forestry mod has a rubber tree farm. That would solve it.

Comment: @Kendra does this tree farm, farm the teardrop shapped rubber nodules, or actualy 'sticky resin'

Comment: From what I remember, its been a while since I used it, it does farm the resin. I will attempt to verify this when I get home.

Comment: I can't find (quickly) a mod list for FTB-Unhinged, so: do you have Forestry? Multi-farms can be configured to extract stick resin from IC2 rubber trees.

Comment: Yes Forestry is included. Ill look into multi-farms thank you

Comment: Don't taps to this? I believe that there is a mechanical tap, and I believe that works on these.

Comment: Oh, wait. Do you mean the really **huge** rubber trees or the little ones that you can use taps on?

Comment: @TheUgly the little ones you can use tree-taps on

Comment: @TheUgly The huge ones aren't in the current FTB packs anymore. They're a part of RedPower, which hasn't updated to 1.5 or later.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie What?! Noo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given access to forestry you can build a [Multi-Block farm](http://forestry.sengir.net/wiki.new/doku.php?id=farms:multi) of whichever [size](http://forestry.sengir.net/wiki.new/doku.php?id=farms:structure)<sup>1</sup> suits [configured](http://forestry.sengir.net/wiki.new/doku.php?id=farms:programming) with [rubberised electron tubes](http://forestry.sengir.net/wiki.new/doku.php?id=crafting:fabricator) for a manual (you plant the trees) rubber farm.

---

<sup>1</sup> Remember you only need the rubber tree logs that actually produce the resin, and no gaps. With a Gravity or Portal gun you can move the useful blocks on to the farm for a high density of production. Given enough time even a quarter of a small farm led to me almost filling an extra dimensional barrel (Factorization): my the time I moved away from that world I think I had something like 900 stacks of rubber.

Comment: Perfect information. I'm glad you found that, Richard. My info was a tad outdated, as I feared. ^^'